# How to debug code of static library (libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib) 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, openssl, static-libraries

I have built openssl static libraries(libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib) with openssl source code using VC++ compiler. I use them in a VS2010 project and they works well.

```
#pragma comment( lib, "libeay32.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "ssleay32.lib" )
```

Then problem is I want to debug the source code of openssl libraries in VS2010(step into, step over...). For example, set a breakpoint in the openssl api and then step into the openssl source file. how can I achieve that?

I have tried to use VS compiler option 'Zi' to generate some .pdb files when building openssl static libraries, but I don't know how to use them. I tried to add the path of those .pdb files in Option->Debugging->Symbols->Symbol file location, but seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you built OpenSSL with debug symbols, i.e. `perl Configure debug-VC-WIN32 ...`? This is normally the only step you need aside from pointing VS to the debug file (do this under project configuration)

Comment: I have done `perl Configure debug-VC-WIN32` but I cannot still step in into openssl methods, can you elaborate about how to point VS to the debug file?

Answer (score 0):

See Jared's answer at [*How to debug external class library projects in visual studio?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654696/how-to-debug-external-class-library-projects-in-visual-studio). In short:

- Debug -> Windows -> Modules
- Find the DLL for the project you are interested in
- Right Click -> Load Symbols -> Select the Path to the .PDB for your other project

Also, make sure the PDB files are in the same directory as `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib`.

Finally, if you are really having trouble, try Thomas Hruska's [*The Win32 OpenSSL Installation Project*](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Thomas prebuilds everything for you and packages it in a Windows installer.