# How to debug class library projects in Rider

Tags: c#, debugging, rider

There is an external application that executes C# libraries(plugins - my class library).
Is it possible to attach debug to my class library project in Rider.
In a Visual Studio, this is done very easily. For example, as described in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13742464/2221795). But how to do it in a Rider?

Thank you

Comment: To be able to debug (without see assembly language) the application need to have debug info (symbols, map, source).  So you have to enable debugging in Rider.  See : https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/documentation/rider_survival_guide.html

Comment: For debugging I have 2 options: 1) .Net Project - but in this mode it is not possible to select a library project for debugging. 2) .Net Executable - but this mode for running .net applications and there is no option to select a host app exe.

Comment: Host app doesn't make a difference.  The debug info is the same structure inside dll (any executable) for all host applications.  The dll structure is a standard interface,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can use .NET Executable for your task. Put your library as command-line arguments into a run configuration. In the future, we want to add the macro for OutputPath.

Comment: any news on that?