# Can hidden fields be edited by the user?

Tags: html, security, hidden-field

adding in security questions so that users may reset their passwords if they exceed maximum attempts. is it bad to do hidden fields such as these for authentication mechanism?

```
<input type="hidden" name="securityAnswered" value=true>
<input type="hidden" name="exceededAttempts" value=true>
```

could a user go in and edit these hidden fields from the client side?

Comment: If you are using google chrome or firefox you can change it simple , just Right-click and select the Inspect Element Item , then you can change the value of client side things

Comment: There Are other programs that do this such as firebug , ...

Comment: In your console, do: `document.querySelector("input[name=securityAnswered]").value = "wibble"`

Answer (score 6):

> could a user go in and edit these hidden fields from the client side?

Of course! Anything on the client side can be edited. You cannot stop users from doing that.

You have to keep in mind that the client can post to the server any content, any time.

Comment: ok, so what would be another way to send this information from the form to the server?

Comment: @rtd353 The validation should be done on the server. There's no other way: the client posts the data and the server receives and **validates** it.

Comment: This is true but I just want to add that you could still use a secure session if you really wanted to save data on the client side.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann Ah, that's a good point! But I guess it's much better to store that information on the server only, in the session.

Comment: @ionica i am validating on the server. i only added the securityAnswered hidden field to the reset password so that way if the user submits invalid password it will indicated that security question has been answered so the user can try reseting again.

Comment: @rtd353 In fact, these values can remain on the server, they don't have to be sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

yes of course , any one can change it by clicking in `ctrl+maj+i`

Comment: Fun Fact: `EN-US` will recognize the `maj` modifier as the `shift` key, albeit with subtle nuances.

Read more in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008486/shift-shortcut-being-displayed-as-maj-for-culture-nl-be-when-it-should-be-shif).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, penetration testers do this all the time using intercepting proxies such as Burp or Zap.

https://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html
  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

There are many other ways of modifying such data, including developer tools in the browser.