# How can I debug /step through ASP.NET Identity methods without PDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, task, async-await, asp.net-identity

I am having a lot of trouble debugging issues with a custom implementation of a `UserStore` that I've created to use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` without Entity Framework. Specifically, I am running into two issues:

1. Since the Identity framework provides a default implementation for many things, and the implementation is hidden, I don't know the steps it takes to do things like `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync` or `AddClaimAsync`
2. Since the Identity framework makes use of the `async` modifier (and I am admittedly not very comfortable/familiar with this yet) this complicates things as I have encountered several instances in which a default implementation failed or returned null. In these cases I had to guess where things might be going wrong

Forgive me if this is a dumb question and/or if it has already been answered but I did not know how to word it appropriately (to find an existing answer)...

I am wondering if there are tools or debugger options that would allow me to step through the interfaces of the Identity framework classes so that I can at least find out how "far" a particular method call got in the process.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654696/how-to-debug-external-class-library-projects-in-visual-studio. Visual Studio can debug external libraries, especially those provided by Microsoft itself. Their pdbs and sources will be downloaded from source code repository. I used Google "visual studio debug external source" to find this article

Comment: Thanks. I think that does it. I voted to close rather than delete so that this can at least help other people get to the right answer.