# Getting error in my asp.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2007

This is the error i am getting when i run my code and try to fetch record

> Keyword not supported: 'provider'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported:
>   'provider'.

My code was working fine i am using Ms Access 2007 . Then i need to add some more column in table after that i getting this error

This is my web.cfg

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='|DataDirectory|\mfaridalam1.accdb'; Persist Security Info=False" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This is how i am getting my connection string using Configuration Manager

```
ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

This is how i am  calling my function

```
 newtable = Class1.GetLastRec(ConnectionString, "LastAlbum");
```

This is my function

```
  public static string GetLastRec(string Connectionstring, string ColumnName)
    {
        // string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AGENTJ.AGENTJ-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\mfaridalam\App_Data\mfaridalam1.accdb;    Persist Security Info=False;";
        string newAlbum = "";
        string conStr = Connectionstring;
        string Column = ColumnName;
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from LastInfo", con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                string input = dr[Column].ToString();
                newAlbum = input;
                if (newAlbum.Substring(0, 1) == "c")
                {
                    //input.Trim();
                    input = input.Substring(3);
                    int cont = Convert.ToInt32(input) + 1;
                    newAlbum = "c00" + cont.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    input = input.Substring(3);
                    int cont = Convert.ToInt32(input) + 1;
                    newAlbum = "v00" + cont.ToString();
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            // Response.Write(newtable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
        return newAlbum;

    }
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  It seems a bit suspect that this is an "unhandled exception" at the request level when the code you show handles exceptions...

Comment: This line throw exception   newtable = Class1.GetLastRec(ConnectionString, "LastAlbum");

Comment: And which line inside of the `GetLastRec()` function throws the exception?  My *guess* is: `OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);`  Can you confirm the runtime value of `conStr` while debugging?

Comment: problem is that i made dll for my class so right now i cant debug that what if i debug that newtable = Class1.GetLastRec(ConnectionString, "LastAlbum")

Comment: You most certainly can debug into that method.  The debugger has a "step into" button to enter a method, or you can put a breakpoint directly in the method's code.  The fact that it's a separate project makes no difference.  Ideally that separate project is still in the same overall solution and is referenced as a Project Reference.  If it *needs* to be a separate DLL reference (and I suspect it really doesn't) then you need to include that code in your debugging context, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/654696/328193