# referencing umbraco 7 source codes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to figure out some of the functions inside umbraco. The documentation is pretty awful. Can't even find some of the basic example functions definitions. 
In example no documentation for creatRegistrationModel,  https://our.umbraco.org/search?q=CreateRegistrationModel&cat=documentation

So I found the github downloaded the project. Compiled without issues. I know i can reference the files which i have done for umbraco.dll but not using the file directly, seems pushing it to Temp folder.

Now I want to reference the solution's project .dll files. And debug step by step into the code, is this possible? if i can go tru the code I could see how its calling some of these functions what kinda actions its taking.

Or should I move the projects into my project and reference inside there giving me single project to manage. not sure even if it would work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to understand about the `CreateRegistrationModel` method? You can see the source for it here https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/d50e49ad37fd5ca7bad2fd6e8fc994f3408ae70c/src/Umbraco.Web/Security/MembershipHelper.cs

Comment: In-order to debug the Umbraco source code and step through line by line, you would need to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654696/how-to-debug-external-class-library-projects-in-visual-studio. You should not really need to debug the Umbraco source code; the assembly explorer in Visual Studio should provide an overview of the API you need. Perhaps specifying any specific requirements will help gain the response you are after.

Comment: As far as documentation goes, I'd recommend installing a neat package called "Bookshelf" https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/bookshelf/. It allows you to import documentation into the umbraco backoffice. One cool source of documentation is this: https://github.com/kgiszewski/LearnUmbraco7. It is a community maintained documentation repository for umbraco 7. Really good stuff in there for both people new to umbraco and people who have been around it for quite a while. You can import that via Bookshelf if you want.