# Debugging C# external classes

Tags: c#

I have a Visual Studio project, and trying to debug it. 
The method is this:

```
IHttpHandler IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
```

I'm trying to figure out from where `requestContext` is coming from. It should come from some external solution. I've implemented [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654696/how-to-debug-external-class-library-projects-in-visual-studio) suggestions, but my stack looks like this (all System methods)

[image]

Not everything should be from System libraries, since `requestContext -> RouteDate -> RouteHandler -> MethodName` contains a method name which is in my current solution, so stack should hit one of my external solutions at some point, but I don't see where.

Comment: That's part of the Asp.Net stack.

Comment: There are a few places that can instantiate an instance of that class.  One is [in `UrlRoutingHandler`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/Routing/UrlRoutingHandler.cs,48)

Comment: You might debug into .NET Framework source code, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2019, but whether it works depends on whether Microsoft published the symbols for the version of .NET Framework you use.